# Oracle stored procedure access to other schemas

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

Thanks for reading this question.

I'm using Oracle 11g. With my user I can run this query and have access to all the schemas with views:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
```

However, when I create a stored procedure with my user in my schema and I put this query inside I don't get access to others users' schemas.
I would suppose that the stored procedure needs to be granted somehow access to other schemas.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Peternac

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures and other PL/SQL constructs cannot use privileges granted through roles. Object privileges - like "select" on a table or view in another schema - must be granted directly to the user. That is almost certainly why you can run your query directly (using your user's role-based privileges) but not as part of a PL/SQL procedure.

If you really need this query to be included in a stored procedure, then you'll have to get with your DBA to work out exactly which object privileges need to be granted directly to your user account.

Answer (score 0):

I am using oracle 12c
and this problem was solved by

```
grant select any table to your_schema;
```